# Nhibernate (Fluent), Ninject.Mvc3, and Web Activator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, ninject, webactivator

I am working on an ASP .NET Mvc 3 App and have installed Ninject.Mvc3 using Nuget.  I now have the App_Start folder and then ninject class.  I have seen plenty of examples on how to configure NHibernate in the Global.asax file.  So how do I configure the session before handing it Ninject if I am using the Web Activator class? Do I just do it like normal in the global.asax?,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bob Cravens has a nice series of posts on how to do this:

Using the Repository Pattern with MVC and NHibernate

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/the-repository-pattern-with-linq-to-fluent-nhibernate-and-mysql/

Using an IoC container (like Ninject) with a NHibernate inside ASP.NET MVC

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/07/using-nhibernate-in-asp-net-mvc/

Any responsible web developer knows that managing / disposing of objects and resources is critical to good web application development. Please make sure and read this bit too :-)

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/11/using-ninject-to-manage-critical-resources/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which example you are refering to. But for most of them you can do it the same way.

Comment: So I have added a begin and end request handler to the global.asax for nhibernate session initialization, but apprently that never gets called so when Ninject provides the session from the provider it is null.

Comment: As I said, I don't know how you are trying to do it. So it is impossible to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now, in App_Start folder you have a file called NinjectMVC.cs, there is a method:

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
    }
```

You have to register all your services there, just the same way you did in global.ascx before.